# How do I change the language on my phone if it is not an available choice?

Tags: languages, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I went to settings > keyboard / language, but my choice language is not available in the list.

Comment: May I know what language do you want to use? Not all languages are supported on every Android phone; it's up to the manufacturer/ROM creator to include the languages or not.

Comment: If the language you want is not available, an [alternative keyboard app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards) *might* be a solution *for the keyboard (input) part*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if you mean the Main System Language or the Keyboard Language!, if you want to add languages for keyboard then follow this steps,
Just connect to wifi or turn on 3g then go to,
Setting > Language and Input > Samsung Keyboard > Languages,
Now it'll ask you if you want to list all available languages, Click Yes and choose the language you want and let it download.